# Share images and videos in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want share images and videos in flutter, I am using easy_flutter_share package, but when I write text,

`await Share.files('Sorted'.tr(), _shareJson, '*/*',
          text: '${_selectedPhotos.length}  ${_shareText}');`

share only text, how can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EsysFlutterShare Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share). You can share any file you like and its working on both, iOS and Android.

Comment: I want to show my own text, but when I select one image and one video to share, automaticly that change my text how can I fix it